# Nesting array of elements as children of each other

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What should the implementation of `nestify()` be to make following components equivalent to each other?

```
const A = nestify([Foo, Bar, Baz]);

const B = props => (
  <Foo>
    <Bar>
      <Baz>{props.children}</Baz>
    </Bar>
  </Foo>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea (assuming the function should handle dynamic arrays) could be a recursive implementation using `React.createElement()`. The 3rd argument for it is the element's children, thus you could pass in the next array element. So something like this in the component:

```
const nestify = (components, children, index = 0) =>
  React.createElement(
    components[index],
    {},
    index === components.length - 1
      ? children
      : nestify(components, children, index + 1)
  );

const A = props => nestify([Foo, Bar, Baz], props.children);
```