# What is the correct way to recursively generate react elements?

Tags: reactjs

I've been trying this, but nothing is being rendered in the DOM.  What is the trick here?

```
recurse(i, arr) {
    if (!i) {
        i = 0;
        arr = [];
    }

    if (i >= 4) {
        return arr;
    }

    arr.push(<div key={i}>hello world</div>);

    this.recurse(i + 1, arr);
}

render() {
    let styles = { height: '100vh', overflow: 'hidden' };

    return <div style={styles}>{this.recurse()}</div>;
}
```

Comment: Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50920827/nesting-array-of-elements-as-children-of-each-other/50921019#50921019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are missing the return in the recursive call:

```
recurse(i, arr) {
    if (!i) {
        i = 0;
        arr = [];
    }

    if (i >= 4) {
        return arr;
    }

    arr.push(<div key={i}>hello world</div>);

    return this.recurse(i + 1, arr);
}

render() {
    let styles = { height: '100vh', overflow: 'hidden' };

    return <div style={styles}>{this.recurse()}</div>;
}
```

**Edit:** If you want each **div** to be rendered recursively as children your recurse function will look a little bit different:

```
recurse(i) {
    if (!i) {
        i = 0;
    }

    if (i >= 4) {
        return;
    }

    return <div  key={i}>hello world{this.recurse(++i)}</div>;
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that.  Do you happen to know how to recursively add children as well?  I've been trying..

arr.push(<div key={i}>hello world{this.recurse()}</div>)

Comment: @ChrisWingler I've edited the answer to recursivly add children.  Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/59269/) to play around.